# C# Save additional information about file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm currently working on a MusicPlayer/RadioPlayer app in Visual Studio(C#), I am really stuck at how can I attach more information to a music file like mp3, not to his id3 tag, I would like to have more than that, like is that song favourited in the application, what was the source the user added it, additional information about it.(can't find anything that fits)
I was thinking about creating xml file for each song they save or edit and mark it as hidden, but then it's gonna use more resources on application startup....does any of you have another approach,idea for this? I would really appreciate it Thx.

Comment: Why not a database like Sqlite? Why does it have to be hidden? What are your concerns about resources?

Comment: Database like an online database or offline database (something similar) one,in a folder next to the app,I was not really looking into databases yet,I wanted it to be hidden so it does not annoy the user,I don't want the program to use alot of cpu or ram to load only one song and it's data...

Comment: Sqlite is not online, it is a flat-file (and very widely used database system). You could also use JSON files, which are smaller and easier to work with than XML. You can have one database for all the songs (would be a single file), one JSON file for all the songs (I wouldn't recommend using JSON like a database, but it can be done), or one for each, that is an architecture choice. I wouldn't worry about CPU or RAM usage, it is comparatively small for this type of metadata.

Comment: Thank you very much for these fast answers, I will look into Sqlite, and try not to use json. If I can ask one more think do you have a specific site to learn more about sqlite and how to make it work? (that you think it's best)If not I will just google search one.

Comment: [Here is one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210189/Using-SQLite-in-Csharp-VB-Net), just google "C# SQLite tutorial" and read some of them, I'd try to use more recent examples because API's change.

Comment: SQLite would be best with this as everyone mentioned above. It would make your life easy to use that than having to deal with bulky XML or parsing JSON